# Check if a Winform CheckBox is checked through WINAPI only

Tags: c#, c++, winforms, winapi, win32gui

my problem goes like this :
I need to check if a winform checkbox from a different program is checked or not by WINAPI only.

here how I catch the underlyined C# HWND: 
first I get all the HWND's of the desktop with EnumWindows and then EnumChildWindows , then I go on each one and with GetWindowText compares my wanted text to the window text and if there is a match - I return it.

just to make things clear - I can catch the underlying HWND. if I print its text and the class name it is the winform checkbox wanted.

now, the checkbox I want to check has WindowsForm.10.BUTTON.app.0.33c0d9d5 class name. with this function I ask it if its a valid checkbox:

```
bool isValid(){
    if(!handleToControl) return false;
    LONG_PTR styles = GetWindowLongPtr(handleToControl, GWL_STYLE);
    bool isCheckBox = ((styles & BS_AUTO3STATE) == BS_AUTO3STATE);
    isCheckBox = isCheckBox || ((styles & BS_AUTOCHECKBOX) == BS_AUTOCHECKBOX);
    isCheckBox = isCheckBox || ((styles & BS_CHECKBOX) == BS_CHECKBOX);
    return isCheckBox;
}
```

now, the function does work (I checked it on many native checkboxes and also winform checkboxes) and it can validate if it's a valid checkbox or not (including the checkbox I want to check)

then , I try to see if the winform checkbox is checked or not with this function:

```
bool isChecked(){
    LRESULT _isChecked = SendMessage(handleToControl, BM_GETCHECK, 0, 0);
    bool ic = !(_isChecked == BST_UNCHECKED);
    if (ic)
        return ic;
    ic = ((Button_GetState(handleToControl) & BST_CHECKED) == BST_CHECKED);
    if (ic)
        return ic;

    return false;
}
```

but I fail miserably. can someone see what's wrong with my idea / code or suggest a different solution?

Comment: [MSDN says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775986(v=vs.85).aspx) `If the button has a style other than those listed, the return value is zero.`, maybe this is the reason why it doesn't work.

Comment: ok , any other ideas how to achieve it?

Comment: The Winforms CheckBox control was re-implemented from scratch, it doesn't use the native Windows control.  So isn't going to respond to BM_GETCHECK.  Nor does it provide an alternative.  You'll need to use UI Automation to get somewhere, plenty of libraries around.

Comment: so why does it response to enumchildwindows , getwindowtext,getclassname etc?

Comment: Because it's still a window, it's just doesn't belong to builtin window class that corresponds to checkbox. I wasn't sure if that's the case with WinForms, thought only WPF draws all its components manually.

Comment: Why do so many people start with hacking rather than using the platform automation library?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan If "so many people" aren't using it, it could be related to performance of functionality. I've used the UI automation a bit for a one-off tool. In my experience it seemed pretty slow and would only return the control's text if the control was visible in the scrollable window.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan because the documentation is poor , the API they provide is not intuitive enough, and code you need to write is huge for pretty basic things (e.g. click a button). plus you are obligated to work on visual studio. and if you already know WinApi , you feel you need to learn something new from scratch to do something you already know in winapi

Comment: @David You don't need to work with VS to use UI Automation. It can be used anywhere that can consume COM objects. Using the wrong tool for the job is what led to this question. Even in the face of all the evidence you are intent on continuing down this dead end.

Comment: I'm the first one to go with the right tools for the right job. BUT , all the other stuff I do with winapi on winform are working very good, and this small thing is pretty marginal in my program. worst case scenario , if it WAS something crucial I could do image manipulation and determine it. I too was negative about the idea to develop automation with winapi , but after many failed python libraries, not so functioning AutoIt AND battling with UI Automation I went with what I know and it is working 98% precent of the time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is using `IAccessibility` an option?

e.g.

(taken from http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/637107-how-find-out-if-check-box-checked)

```
[DllImport("oleacc.dll")]
internal static extern int AccessibleObjectFromWindow(IntPtr hwnd, uint id, ref Guid iid, [In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] ref object ppvObject); 

internal enum OBJID : uint
{
    WINDOW = 0x00000000,
    SYSMENU = 0xFFFFFFFF,
    TITLEBAR = 0xFFFFFFFE,
    MENU = 0xFFFFFFFD,
    CLIENT = 0xFFFFFFFC,
    VSCROLL = 0xFFFFFFFB,
    HSCROLL = 0xFFFFFFFA,
    SIZEGRIP = 0xFFFFFFF9,
    CARET = 0xFFFFFFF8,
    CURSOR = 0xFFFFFFF7,
    ALERT = 0xFFFFFFF6,
    SOUND = 0xFFFFFFF5,
}

public const long UNCHECKED = 1048576;
public const long CHECKED = 1048592;
public const long UNCHECKED_FOCUSED = 1048580; // if control is focused
public const long CHECKED_FOCUSED = 1048596; // if control is focused

private static bool IsChecked(IntPtr handle) {
    Guid guid = new Guid("{618736E0-3C3D-11CF-810C-00AA00389B71}");
    Object obj = null;
    int retValue = AccessibleObjectFromWindow(handle, (uint) OBJID.CLIENT, ref guid, ref obj);

    if (obj is IAccessible) {
        IAccessible accObj = (IAccessible) obj;
        Object result = accObj.get_accState(0);
        if (result is int) {
            int state = (int) result;
            return (state == CHECKED || state == CHECKED_FOCUSED);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Er, surely you mean UI automation

Comment: @DavidHeffernan No, I think they are different. You have to add the `Accessibility` reference to the project, which is separate from UI automation. I could be wrong though.

Comment: I will try it in native C++. do you think the line `obj is IAccessible` can be translated to `if(dynamic_cast<IAccessible>(someVaribale))` ?

Comment: In the case of this code you pass `IID_IAccessible` to `AccessibleObjectFromWindow()`; if the object is not an IAccessible the function will fail with `E_NOINTERFACE`, so there is no need for that statement at all. (It shouldn't not be IAccessible; `AccessibleObjectFromWinow()` was designed for IAccessible...) What David Hefferman is suggesting is that you use the newer UI Automation API instead of the ancient MSAA API. The code is different but the idea is the same. Loathing's own software might benefit as well since UI Automation was designed with .net in mind.

Comment: I am so grateful for this page/comments. It took me hours (sadly) to learn that checkboxes with style always return Zero (using BM_GETCHECK message) when (as originally pointed out by xaizek): `If the button has a style other than those listed, the return value is zero.` and I am also very grateful for this piece of code because it's working. :)